# Passing a variable to a function through a button (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, button

I'm attempting to create a page that will allow me to select from a series of images, with the option of choosing your own via URL, but I have stumbled on an issue. I am attempting to use buttons placed under the sample images to change the source image that is piped into a function, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function updateImage(imageUsed)
{
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imageUsed,0,0,500,500);
}
</script>
<style>
#header
{
    background-color:brown;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

#defaultSelection
{
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}

#canvasID
{
    background-color:grey;
    width:1000px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body"> 
<div id="header">
<h1> Welcome</h1>
<h2>Please select an image, or upload your own below.</h2>
</div>
<div id="defaultSelection">
<img id="Image1" src="Image1.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage(Image1)">Use this image</button>
<br>
<img id="Image2" src="Image2.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage(Image2)">Use this image</button>
<br>
<img id="Image3" src="Image3.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage()">Use this image</button>
<br>
<img id="Image4" src="Image4.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage()">Use this image</button>
</div>
<div id="canvasID">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color:white;">
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why it might not be passing the images through? They display correctly on the page, so I know the source is correct, but they don't seem to want to be passed to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your javascript function to:

```
function updateImage(imageUsed) {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
        ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
        image = document.getElementById(imageUsed);
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,500,500);
}
```

Then output your buttons like:

```
<button onclick="updateImage('Image1')">Use this image</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, can you mark one of the answers as the selected answer? It looks like they all pretty much say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ID of the element as a string

```
<button onclick="updateImage('Image1')">Use this image</button>
```

and in updateImage method you need get the image object from the passed ID

```
function updateImage(imageUsed)
{
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    **imageUsed = document.getElementById(imageUsed);**
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imageUsed,0,0,500,500);
}
```

Here is the full working code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function updateImage(imageUsed)
{
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    imageUsed = document.getElementById(imageUsed);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imageUsed,0,0,500,500);
}
</script>
<style>
#header
{
    background-color:brown;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

#defaultSelection
{
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}

#canvasID
{
    background-color:grey;
    width:1000px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body"> 
<div id="header">
<h1> Welcome</h1>
<h2>Please select an image, or upload your own below.</h2>
</div>
<div id="defaultSelection">
<img id="Image1" src="Image1.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage('Image1')">Use this image</button>
<br>
<img id="Image2" src="Image2.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage('Image2')">Use this image</button>
<br>
<img id="Image3" src="Image3.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage('Image3')">Use this image</button>
<br>
<img id="Image4" src="Image4.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px">
<br>
<button onclick="updateImage('Image4')">Use this image</button>
</div>
<div id="canvasID">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; background-color:white;">
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to load the image, so it can find the URL

```
function updateImage(imageUsed)
{
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById(imageUsed);
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,500,500);
}
```